# Get Latest run time of SQL maintenance jobs

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am trying to get the status of maintenance jobs in SQL using the below query.

```
USE msdb
GO
SELECT Distinct SJ.Name AS "Jobs/Sql ServerInstances",
CONVERT(date, getdate(),101) as "Date last monitored",
SJH.run_date AS "Date last run", 
CASE SJH.run_status 
WHEN 0 THEN 'Failed'
WHEN 1 THEN 'Successful'
WHEN 3 THEN 'Cancelled'
WHEN 4 THEN 'In Progress'
END AS LastRunStatus
FROM sysjobhistory SJH, sysjobs SJ
WHERE SJH.job_id = SJ.job_id and SJH.run_date = 
(SELECT MAX(SJH1.run_date) FROM sysjobhistory SJH1 WHERE SJH.job_id = SJH1.job_id)
and SJ.Name  like '%DB%'
ORDER BY SJH.run_date desc
```

And below is the result which it returns.

```
Jobs/Sql ServerInstances    Date last monitored Date last run   LastRunStatus
DB_BackuPlan.15min_trx      2016-11-04          20161104        Failed
DB_BackuPlan.15min_trx      2016-11-04          20161104        Successful
DB_BackuPlan.Differential   2016-11-04          20161104        Successful
DB_BackuPlan.Full           2016-11-04          20161029        Successful
```

However, I want to return only the latest record for the transaction log backup. I understand that DISTINCT keyword will search on a row level and not on a column level,(and hence returning me two results, one for status failed and the other for status successful for the same job).
Is there a way by which I can return only the latest run information for the above jobs?

Comment: I tried using the TOP keyword. But unfortunately, it doesn't return the status for my differential backup and full backup. I was wondering if there's a way to eliminate the duplicate based on the job name itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added the below changes:

Due to sysjobhistory saves `run_date` and `run_time` using two different (int) fields, it is possible that `SELECT Top 1 [instance_id] ... order by [run_date] desc` doesn't return the desired row.

To solve that, I've changed it by:

```
order by dbo.agent_datetime(run_date,run_time) desc
```

that returns a `datetime` value using both `[run_date]` and `[run_time]`

```
use msdb
go

with jobs_cte as
(
select 
    sj.[job_id]
    ,sj.[name]
    ,[date last monitored] = convert(datetime, getdate(), 101)
    ,[instance_id] = (select top 1 [instance_id] 
                      from [sysjobhistory] 
                      where [sysjobhistory].job_id = sj.job_id 
                      order by dbo.agent_datetime(run_date,run_time) desc)
from 
    sysjobs sj
where 
    sj.[name] like '%DB%'
)
select
    jobs_cte.job_id
    ,jobs_cte.[name]
    ,[date last monitored]
    , case [sjh].[run_status]
        when 0 then 'Failed'
        when 1 then 'Successful'
        when 3 then 'Cancelled'
        when 4 then 'In Progress'
    end as [lastrunstatus]
from
    jobs_cte
    left join sysjobhistory sjh
        on jobs_cte.instance_id = sjh.instance_id
```

Comment: @VivekKumar is there any problem with the answer?

Comment: I ran the above query. For instance_id (of the transaction log backup job), it is returning me the Id for the failed step.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand, [instance_id] is not correct?

Comment: Sorry for the partial description. Was having issues with my machine.
Actually, the query (select top 1 [instance_id]  from [sysjobhistory] where [sysjobhistory].job_id = sj.job_id order by [job_id],[run_date] desc) was returning to me the instance_id of the job for the step at which it had failed. The job had failed at 3:30 AM EST, but was successful at the next run that was 3:45 AM EST. Ideally the result which the query should have returned (if it is run after 3:45 AM) should contain the instance_id of the 3:45 AM run, but it was still giving me the instance_id of 3:30 AM run.

Comment: That was just a bit confusing. I figured if I could order by [instance_id] desc then i would be able to get the desired result. And it happened too. Thanks for the solution @mcNets! :)

Comment: @VivekKumar take a look at last modifications.